# Broken Package Error in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu

I tried to install some kali linux tools. I was using a thirdparty script called katoolin that adds kali linux repo in source list. I installed aroung 20-25 tools and I restarted my laptop. It then thow some error after log in. Then, I thought it was gnome desktop causing it. So I removed it. Then I installed xfce(xubuntu-desktop). Now I am getting error message while installing new package. In grub menu I can see kalilinux image banner instead of ubuntu's. But while booting it boots ubuntu. I have only ubuntu installed.

```
    sudo apt install inkscape
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-10 : Depends: cpp-10 (= 10.2.0-5) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libcc1-0 (>= 10.2.0-5) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libgcc-10-dev (= 10.2.0-5) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-10-base : Breaks: gcc-10-base:i386 (!= 10.2.0-5) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-10-base:i386 : Breaks: gcc-10-base (!= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 inkscape : Depends: libgsl23 (>= 2.5) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libgtkspell0 (>= 2.0.10) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libpotrace0 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libimage-magick-perl but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: python-lxml but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: python-numpy but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: python-scour but it is not installable
 lib32gcc1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libgcc-s1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libgfortran5 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libobjc4 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 libubsan1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.2.0-5 is to be installed
 resetter : Depends: python-qt4 (>= 4.10) but it is not installable
            Depends: python-apt (>= 0.9.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python-mechanize (>= 1:0.2.5) but it is not installable
            Depends: python-bs4 (>= 4.2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: add-apt-key (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to remove the Kali sources in /etc/apt.sources.list.d/

Comment: No, I have deleted everything, I am sure about that.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` after removing those sources?  What is the output of `apt-cache policy inkspace` and `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: for apt-cache policy inkscape:

inkscape:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.92.5-1ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     0.92.5-1ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.92.5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages


for lsb_release -a: 

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Comment: Please [edit] your question and append the output. Formatting in comments make it hard to read outputs in comments.